# App Crashes at Apple but not in test

Tags: iphone, crash, app-store-connect, submission, route-me

My app has been (correctly) rejected by Apple as it crashes when you try to use the offline maps.  The crash is in the route-me code libraries so the crash log isn't that helpful.  In test it is fine, and does not crash, so I can't recreate the test condition successfully.

I am running on the same version of iOS (4.3.3) as Apple. I've tried forcing the location code to return a location on California.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

When I had problems with getting an app accepted to the App Store on Apple's end but not my own it ended up being some of the build dependencies for an external library I was using. I had set them in my Debug build but not my Release builds. Since I didn't test on Release builds, I never noticed the crashing. Apple did however, since that's what I sent them.

Comment: Thanks @josholat.  I've now recreated the fault - its on the Release build.  However, I can't see any difference between the release and other builds that I think would make a difference.  My suspicion is that the release build of the main project is bringing in a non release build of one of the two dependent projects that make up route-me.  I just don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue on their end.

This happened to me ( [iPhone Crash with "No Backtrace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222142/iphone-crash-with-no-backtrace) ). I resubmitted with no changes and my app was approved. Months later I have never reproduced or heard complaints of a single crash.

I'd recommend resubmitting an identical binary. While you wait for approval, try re-running a clean build, deleting and reinstalling the app from your device, and ad-hoc testing on "clean" devices that you haven't deployed to before to try and reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Apple. When I was running my app with offline maps on the iPhone simulator, iPhones or iPad, I had no problem. But with Instrument, the app was crashing when I set the delegate of the MapView to the ViewController.

The way to fix is really simple :
Had the code `[RMMapView class];` just before the `[mapView setDelegate:self];`.

If I remember correctly, the compiler was not able to find a .xib file. Sorry don't remember exactly why I made this, but it works.